# Unplugging a Blu-Ray player as it's playing the movie — cause physical disc damage?

Tags: disc

Does suddenly cutting power to a CD/DVD/Blu-Ray player when it's loaded with a spinning disc cause physical damage to the disc?

Comment: It shouldn't ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cd / dvd / Blu-ray Disc works by using a laser to read and write data.

Nothing physically touches the disc surface. Only the spindle motor engages the center of the disc to spin it.

It’s not possible to damage the disc by cutting power to the unit, as the only thing that will happen is the disc will stop spinning.

Comment: I always STOP my stereo to allow CDs to come to a rest before turning it off; I guess now I don't need to!

Comment: When a tray-loading drive loses power, does it keep the disc picked up (raised), or does it get dropped onto the tray?

Comment: @grawity I’m not aware of any unit that does that. The tray action and spindle are typically connected together in one motion and driven by one motor. As the tray opens the spindle drops out of the way and vice-versa. It doesn’t make a whole lot of sense to do it differently because there would be a lot of drawbacks, like damaging the disc, complexity and cost. I can’t say there isn’t any unit out there that doesn’t do that, but I bet they would buffer the disc in someway to account for the power loss rather than drop it violently.